# How to split a lengthy graphql_schema.rs into modules

Tags: rust, graphql

I am working on an application using Rust with Diesel(2.0), Postgres and Graphql (Juniper 14.2), Actix Web.

However  in the Graphql schema.rs the mutation root and query root implementations are very lengthy with at least 20  API's exposed.

Please advise on how to achieve modularity here. I have split lengthy code into functions and call them with mod and use but am unable to find any help on Graphql schema mutation and query roots.

Thank you.